# Python: QuickBooks API integration

Tags: python, api, quickbooks

Good afternoon,

I've spent the better part of today trying to export the P&L from my QBO sandbox company into a python dataframe (or at least a dictionary). I've been following the instructions [here](https://github.com/ej2/python-quickbooks) but cannot for the life of me get the authentication to work.
I've been using the [OAuth playground](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer) to generate my authorization token, and have the code below:

```
from intuitlib.client import AuthClient
from intuitlib.enums import Scopes
import csv

reader = csv.DictReader(open("/home/mike/home_health/quickbooks_details.csv"))
credentials = next(reader) 

auth_client = AuthClient(
    client_id=credentials.get('client_id'),
    client_secret=credentials.get('secret'),
    redirect_uri='https://developer.intuit.com/v2/OAuth2Playground/RedirectUrl',
    environment='sandbox')

auth_client.get_bearer_token(auth_code='MY_AUTH_CODE', realm_id='MY_REALM_ID')


from quickbooks import QuickBooks

client = QuickBooks(
    auth_client=auth_client,
    refresh_token=auth_client.refresh_token,
    company_id=credentials.get('company_id'),
)

client.get_report(report_type='ProfitAndLoss')
```

Try as I might, I keep getting the following error:

```
AuthorizationException: QB Auth Exception: Application authentication failed 

{"warnings":null,"intuitObject":null,"fault":{"error":[{"message":"message=DispatcherError; errorCode=003100; statusCode=401","detail":"","code":"3100","element":null}],"type":"AUTHENTICATION"},"report":null,"queryResponse":null,"batchItemResponse":[],"attachableResponse":[],"syncErrorResponse":null,"requestId":null,"time":1617720333515,"status":null,"cdcresponse":[]}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What value have you put in `company_id`?

Answer (score 3):

Everything seems right, just am not sure what value you have put for `company_id`. For the `company_id` variable in `client` set it's value as the `Realm Id` that you have and try running it. This works for me

```
from intuitlib.client import AuthClient
from quickbooks import QuickBooks
import os

auth_client = AuthClient(
    client_id=os.getenv('CLIENT_ID'),
    client_secret=os.getenv('CLIENT_SECRET'),
    access_token=os.getenv('ACCESS_TOKEN'),
    environment='sandbox',
    redirect_uri='https://developer.intuit.com/v2/OAuth2Playground/RedirectUrl',
)

client = QuickBooks(
    auth_client=auth_client,
    refresh_token=os.getenv('REFRESH_TOKEN'),
    company_id=os.getenv('REALM_ID'),
)

client.get_report(report_type='ProfitAndLoss')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from intuitlib.client import AuthClient
from intuitlib.enums import Scopes
import csv
from quickbooks import QuickBooks

auth_client = AuthClient(
    client_id=credentials.get('client_id'),
    client_secret=credentials.get('secret'),
    redirect_uri='https://developer.intuit.com/v2/OAuth2Playground/RedirectUrl',
    environment='sandbox')

client = QuickBooks(
    auth_client=auth_client,
    refresh_token=auth_client.refresh_token,
    company_id=credentials.get('company_id'),
)
```

client.get_report(report_type='ProfitAndLoss')

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.

Comment: Okk @Destroy666